# is there a plugin that allow editing pages from within pages without entering admin panel?

Tags: plugins

Is there a plugin that allows editing pages/posts without going to admin panel?

I've a specific need to disallow access for users to admin panel of wordpress/multisite users. But I want them to be able to change contents of pre-structured pages.

is this possible? anyone already thought of this before me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried  the [Front End Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/) plugin to allow users to edit the pages on the site?

> Front-end Editor is a plugin that lets you make changes to your content directly from your site. No need to load the admin backend just to correct a typo. You can edit posts, pages, custom post types, comments, widgets and many more elements.

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.